# Which is the best way of implement auth protected routes in React Router V4?

Tags: react-router-v4

Which is the best way of implement auth protected routes in React Router V4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit of an open question as your auth requirements may not be the same as someone elses however there is an example in the V4 documentation.

[V4 auth routing example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/examples/auth-workflow)

Comment: Unfortunately one can not use async tests inside the Route definitions. In the official examples they do a synchronous test. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142758/trouble-adapting-official-react-router-v4-redirectauth-example-to-make-async-r?noredirect=1#comment79247546_46142758